# Wordcloud titles not showing/rendering in R

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, word-cloud, tidytext

So I performed a sentiment analysis using tidy principles. I would like to plot the results in a comparison cloud (positive VS negative sentiments).

This is my code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidytext)

dtm_tidy %>%
filter()
dtm_tidy %>%
inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"),by=c(term="word")) %>%
count(term, sentiment, sort=TRUE) %>%
acast(term ~ sentiment, value.var = "n", fill = 0) %>%
comparison.cloud(colors = c("darkred", "darkgreen"), max.words=300, scale = c(0.3, 0.3), random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.25, title.size = 1)
```

However, something seems to go wrong, because the titles (positive & negative) are not shown or rendered. I already changed scales and title.size but nothing could solve this issue.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and it's difficult to help without any sample data and a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The lines `dtm_tidy %>% filter()` seem superfluous, as you're not filtering anything.

Comment: Oh of course, I forgot to delete the lines `dtm_tidy %>% filter()`sorry!

Comment: Is there a way to move the titles up and down the Y-axis?

Comment: Please provide sample data and an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem -- the titles were being cutoff on the top and the bottom of the rendered plot when I tried to save it as a pdf.

I was able to get the correct plot output by using "Portrait" orientation instead of "Landscape."  I'm not sure why that fixed the issue but it did when saving it as a pdf or an image.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem: if this issue occurs to you, use the `fixed.asp=TRUE`command. Something like this:

```
comparison.cloud(colors = c("darkred", "darkgreen"), max.words=300, scale = c(0.3, 0.3), random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.25,fixed.asp=TRUE,title.size = 1)
```

This should do the trick! :)